# Java Error in SizeOf library

Tags: java, instrumentation, objectsize

I saw [this link](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/)  which uses `Instrumentation` to calculate the size of objects during runtime. I decided to try this library since It can be really helpful in determining the size of big data structures.
So I wrote the following code in a new project named `TrySizeOf` using `NetBeans` IDE:

```
package trysizeof;
import net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf;

public class TrySizeOf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc";
        System.out.println(SizeOf.deepSizeOf(s));
    }

}
```

After that I created a folder named `lib` inside my project, and placed `SizeOf.jar` in it. Then under `Project->Properties->Run` I placed the following parameter:

> -javaagent:/home/MyUserName/NetBeansProjects/TrySizeOf/lib/SizeOf.jar

However, when I attempt to run my project I get the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/MyUserName/NetBeansProjects/TrySizeOf/lib/SizeOf.jar
>
> agent library failed to init: instrument

Can any one help me with this? or maybe explain what did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I found the error, it was a problem with the upper and lower cases. When I started the project for the first time I made a little upper and lower case typo. When I paid attention to it I fixed it, but I kept getting the same error (However the path was fixed). Now, I tried using clean and build and the project worked. It was that when I do a clean and build `manifest` file gets updated which is used to specify the path of premain method. When I tried clean and build the file got updated and the project finally worked. Thanks for the comment about a typo in my post, which somehow made me think about this.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? `You have to specify full path to JRebel, for example -javaagent:C:programsjrebel.jar or on Linux -javaagent:/home/user/jrebel.jar`

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. Why should I specify full path to JRebel? The link of the library mentioned clearly that I have to add the path of SizeOf.jar only